# Missing Google/Gmail logo from Flutter icons class

Tags: flutter

Going through https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html I couldn't find Google/Gmail logo icon. Is this really missing?

Comment: Just use Fontawesome for logos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right, Google or Gmail Icon are not included in Flutter Material icons library, but you can use [font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter) like this:

```
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

....................


Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // Google Icon
            FaIcon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.google,
              size: 60,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            // Gmail Icon
            FaIcon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.envelope,
              size: 60,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ],
        )
```

[image]

if `font_awesome_flutter` is not the thing that you want, you have to use the Google and Gmail Icons as a custom image in png or svg or etc formats.

happy coding...